# Using <> in an assert statement in OCaml causes error

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, assert

So this might be a stupid question, but I am running into an error in utop right now after just beginning to use OCaml. I am trying to assert that two ints are structurally not equal.

```
assert 2 <> 3;;
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type
   bool because it is in the condition of an assertion
```

The entire statement causes an error, but simply typing the expression I am asserting correctly evaluates to true.

```
2 <> 3;;
- : bool = true
```

I added parentheses to the original assert statement and that fixes the problem.

```
assert (2 <> 3);;
- : unit = ()
```

I am just wondering what exactly happened without the parentheses to cause the error initially. When do you need parentheses typically?

Comment: Hi @esk. It seems that Ken's answer is quite clear. Could you mark it as accepted (to indicate the question is resolved) or else elaborate in a comment what other information you'd like to see? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't sure how to do that, it is my first time using the site. Is it the checkmark?

Comment: no worries at all! It is indeed the check mark, as you worked out already. Welcome to SO! I wish you many answered questions and much fun with OCaml :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with precedence, which determines how "eagerly" a parsing rule is applied. `assert` has a relatively high precedence, higher than `<>` and other operations. This means that this expression

```
assert 2 <> 3
```

is parsed as

```
(assert 2) <> 3
```

and not as

```
assert (2 <> 3)
```

You can find the full table of precedence here: https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec133